# ElasticSearch mixing query types

Tags: node.js, lucene, elasticsearch

I'm having a profoundly hard time getting this elasticsearch query to cooperate. I'm currently trying to use a Bool Query to get results for both exact and analyzed/fulltext searches.

Seems I cannot, for what ever reason, use `match` filters inside a bool query:

```
{
   "bool":{
      "should":[
         "match":{"mainInfo.states": "Wisconsin"},
         "match":{"mainInfo.cities": "WI"}
      ]
   }
}
```

This throws a parser error, telling me that match is not a query type.

I need the ability to have fulltext searches inside of a bool query that also has term filters. So essentially I'd like to have a query somewhat like this:

```
{
   "bool":{
      "must":[
         "term":{"mainInfo.clientId":"123456"}
      ],
      "should":[
         "match":{"mainInfo.states": "Wisconsin"},
         "match":{"mainInfo.cities": "WI"}
      ]
   }
}
```

Where I can have 1 or 2 terms which *must* exists, and several fulltext searches where 2 of them should exist.

I'm also using a function_score query to return random, page-able results using a `random_seed`.

My problem is that I cannot get fulltext queries to run inside of my bool query. Seems that only `term` filters work. Also when I put the `match` queries out of the bool query, it seems that either the match query works, or the bool query works, but never both.

I cannot seem to form a query that will match several `term` queries, and several match queries. The `term` **must** exist, where as the `match` **should** exist(so at least matching one of the filters).

I'm by no means an elasticsearch expert, and the docs seem pretty vague when you're looking for information on more complicated queries.

If anyone could lend an example as how to query in such a manner, it would be greatly appreciated. However, please don't just link me to the docs for Bool Queries, or any other ElasticSearch docs. I assure you I've read them thoroughly, and I've tried a number of different ways to execute this query, but none seem to have the expected behavior.

I'm using ElasticSearch 1.3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Seems I cannot, for what ever reason, use match filters inside a bool query:***

The syntax of your query is not correct, if you have multiple clauses each clause should be wrapped in their own object:

```
{
  "query":{
    "custom_filters_score":{
      "query":{
        "nested":{
          "path":"mainInfo",
          "query":{
            "bool":{
              "should":[
                {
                  "match":{
                    "mainInfo.states":"WI"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "match":{
                    "mainInfo.cities":"Wisconsin"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "filters":[{
        "term":{
          "mainInfo.clientId":"123456"
        },
        "script":"yourscriptgoeshere"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems I'm only getting `clientId`, or which ever of these comes last in the object. I seem to be getting the results of either the term or the match queries but never both.

I feel this is the result of using a "function_score" query

Comment: Can you post an example of your mapping?

Comment: Are you using nested types?

Comment: The mapping is huge, clientId is not_analyzed, as it doesn't need to be. Cities and States are analyzed. Yes I'm using nested types, but as of recent versions of ElasticSearch referring nested types with a format such as `parent.child` should work just fine, and it does. However when I use your example above to make a `function_score` query, I only get results for the given clientId, but not the states or cities provided. I am using a function_score query rather than a filtered query. Filtered queries work just fine.

Comment: If you have a `nested` type you need to use a `nested` query. I have updated my answer assuming that `mainInfo` is `nested`. For more info have a look at: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html

Comment: This filtered query does work, however I'd like to use a funtion_score query to operate the same kind of query. I need the ability to random_score.

Comment: I edited the query to use a `custom_filter_score`. For more info have a look here. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not defining my own scoring script. ElasticSearch supports random_scoring via a seed, however that's `function_score` query type. I found out what I was doing wrong. `function_scores` can only have a filter __or__ a query, but never both. So I was able to just put everything inside a bool query. Seems my problem with `match` was the fact that I was trying to use `match` in a bool _filter_, you cannot use queries in filters unless you wrap them in a query object. However, I need scoring so I must use a query, because fitlers don't score.

Comment: I'll give you the answer, because my question was confusing, and you answered it for the most part.